# tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None) returns False

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running an NVIDIA GeFOrce MX150. I've installed CUDA toolkit v10, cuDNN, and tensorflow-gpu.

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:32:27_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2019-11-23 20:57:00.621530: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
>>> tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
True
>>> tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
2019-11-23 20:57:35.881189: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2019-11-23 20:57:35.886829: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2019-11-23 20:57:35.904122: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
2019-11-23 20:57:35.913593: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: [REDACTED]
2019-11-23 20:57:35.916327: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: [REDACTED]
False
```

Can someone help with what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've installed CUDA 10.2. Maybe it's worth trying the recommended version 10.0? Check [tensorflow gpu software requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements) for details. It's also mentioned in [windows setup section.](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup)
Here is a link to CUDA 10.0 [download](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive)

Comment: No luck, same error
`failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error`